# Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) hybrid - Error Install

Tags: kubernetes, service, stack, azure-aks, hybrid

During AKS installation on stack hci fails without more details

Notification details
ErrorError
Set platform configurations

Source
Go to Azure Kubernetes Service.
Type
Error

Message
Applying platform configurations failed. Error: The provided configuration is not valid. Please review the report moc_validation_report.html, fix the configuration and retry.

Resolve issues and errors during an AKS hybrid installation

Answer (score 0):

Verify your Vnet Config, if you use different VLANs for AKS and host Management. Enable full traffic between it. Make sure the cloudcidr is set from host network.